# GXT How to Get Map property of BeanModel

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I have a DTO, which looks a bit like this:

```
class Response {
  Long id;
  Locale locale;
  Map<Integer,QuestionResponse> questionResponses=new HashMap<Integer,QuestionResponse>();
  ...
}
```

But I'm having trouble mapping a `ColumnConfig` to the `value` property of a `questionResponses` map entry. For example, I want something like this:

```
beanModel.get("questionResponses[15].value")
```

I can see from the get method in `BeanModelData` that I should be able to get a property of a Map but can't figure out the syntax. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use a [DataReader](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-3.0.0/javadoc/gxt/com/sencha/gxt/data/shared/loader/DataReader.html) to map your Response to a new Model

```
final ListLoader<BaseListLoadResult<BeanModel>> loader = new BaseListLoader<BaseListLoadResult<BeanModel>>(
        proxy, new MyBeanModelReader());
loader.load();
new ListStore<BeanModel>(loader); //TODO

public class MyBeanModelReader implements DataReader<List<BeanModel>> {

    private BeanModelReader reader = new BeanModelReader();

    public boolean isFactoryForEachBean() {
        return reader.isFactoryForEachBean();
    }

    public List<BeanModel> read(Object loadConfig, Object data) {
        List<BeanModel> newModelsData = new ArrayList<BeanModel>();
        ListLoadResult<ModelData> models = reader.read(loadConfig, data);
        List<ModelData> modelsData = models.getData();
        for (ModelData modelData : modelsData) {
            BeanModel model = (BeanModel) modelData;
            Response response = (Response) model.getBean();
            model.set("id", response.getId());
            model.set("locale", response.getLocale());
            model.set("QuestionResponse15", response.getQuestionResponse().get(...));  //retrieve the QR you want
            newModelsData.add(model);
        }
        return newModelsData;
    }

    public void setFactoryForEachBean(boolean factoryForEachBean) {
        reader.setFactoryForEachBean(factoryForEachBean);
    }

}
```